# C# - only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

I got the the following error when I use a code:

> only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement

I get this when I use this code:

```
for (int i = enemies.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-) 
{ 
 enemies[i].Update(gameTime);
 if (enemies[i].Active == false)
 {
  enemies.RemoveAt(i);
 }
}
```

PS: I get the error on I- first line : I >= 0; I-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a class level issue, but more likely it is that you are not decrementing `i` properly.

It should read:

```
for (int i = enemies.Count -1; i >= 0; i--) { // etc... }
```

You are just using `i-` which is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

Use `i--` to decrement.  Use two minuses.
This is the equivalent of `i -= 1;` or `i = i - 1;` It is the expression that progresses the iteration

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your for statement, you only have `i-` not `i--`.

Since `i-` is not an operation it is viewed as a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your error located in this row:

```
for (int i = enemies.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-)
```

You need to use this code:

```
for (int i = enemies.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant i--

```
for (int i = enemies.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

The error message indicates that some piece of code is not a complete statement. For this line, there are 3 "statements":

```
int i = enemies.COunt -1;
i >= 0;
i-;
```

If you imagine writing these lines outside of the for loop declaration, you immediately see that i- is not a complete line of code.

```
only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

Translated into easy wording:

```
Only assignemnt (variable = value), call ( DoSomething() ), increment (i++), decrement, (i--), await (await DoSomethingAsync() ), and new object (new List<Object>() ) expression can be used as a statement
```